# loader.setPath is not a function error in threejs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, three.js

I'm getting this error when try to load 3d gltf model on Webgl renderer in threejs, can anyone tell me what I'm doing is wrong.

**here's my code**

```
const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

loader.setPath( 'https://threejs.org/examples/models/gltf/DamagedHelmet/glTF/' );

loader.load( 'DamagedHelmet.gltf', function ( gltf ) {

  gltf.scene.scale.setScalar(2);

  base.add( gltf.scene );

} );

var plane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), -2);

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

var pointOfIntersection = new THREE.Vector3();

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);

function onMouseMove(event){

  mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;

    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

  raycaster.ray.intersectPlane(plane, pointOfIntersection);

  base.lookAt(pointOfIntersection);

}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {

  if (resize(renderer)) {

    camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;

    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

});
```

I'm using latest version of three.js cdn and gltf loader . Any kind of help would be helpful cuz I'm new to this technology.